# Control $\dot x = x+u, u=u(t)$, from $x(0)=3$ to $x(t_1)=2$, s.t $J = \int_0^{t_1} x^2+ux+u^2 \: dt$ is minimized

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization

Control $\dot x = x+u, u=u(t)$ unconstrained, from $x(0)=3$ to $x(t_1)=2$, s.t $J = \int_0^{t_1} x^2+ux+u^2 \: dt$ is minimized. Find, the optimal control $u^*$, optimal path $x^*$  and $t_1$

**Attempt**

Using PMP, $H = -(x^2+ux+u^2) + \psi (x+u)$

Costate eqns:
$\displaystyle \dot \psi = -\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}= 2x + u -\psi$

Maximize $H$ as a fn of $u$:

\begin{align}
    0 &= \frac{\partial H}{\partial u} = -x -2u + \psi
    \Longrightarrow u = \frac{1}{2}(\psi - x)
\end{align}
which is a max since $\frac{\partial^2 H}{\partial u^2} =-2$

$\Longrightarrow \dot \psi = 2x + u -\psi = 2x + \frac{1}{2}(\psi - x) - \psi = \frac{3}{2}x -\frac{1}{2}\psi$

and $\dot x = x+u = {x+\psi \over 2}$

Solving the ode system gives $x = Ae^t+Be^{-t}$ and $\psi =Ae^t-3Be^{-t}$

$H(t_1)=0 \Longrightarrow x = 2\pm \sqrt{-12 + 4\psi +\psi^2}$

If $x = 2 - \sqrt{-12+4\psi(0)+\psi(0)^2}$

For $t=0$
\begin{align*}
x(0) &= 3 = 2 - \sqrt{-12+4\psi(0)+\psi(0)^2} = A+B \\
    \Longrightarrow - 1 &= \sqrt{-12+4(A-3(3-A))+(A-3(3-A))^2} \quad \text{is impossible}
\end{align*}
so no solution for $x=2 - \sqrt{-12+4\psi(0)+\psi(0)^2}$

If $x= 2 +\sqrt{-12+4\psi(0)+\psi(0)^2}$

For $t=0 \Longrightarrow A= \frac{1}{4}(7\pm\sqrt{17})$

If $A= \frac{1}{4}(7+\sqrt{17}), B = 3-A$, at $x(t_1)=2=Ae^{t_1}+Be^{-t_1} \Longrightarrow t_1 <0$

If $A= \frac{1}{4}(7-\sqrt{17}), B = 3-A$ there is no solution for $t_1$

> The system can't be controlled from $x(0)=3$ to $x(t_1)=2$ for $t_1>0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find a stationary point of 
$$
L(x,ψ,u,T) = \int_0^T[H(x,ψ,u)-ψ\dot x]dt
$$

For the variation of this functional with two final times $T$ and $T+δT>T$ use some smooth continuation of $u$. Then $x(T)=(x+δx)(T+δT)$. The variation can now be computed, ignoring terms quadratic or higher in the increments, as \begin{align}
\delta L&=L(x+δx,ψ+δψ,u+δu,T+δT)-L(x,ψ,u,T)\\
&=\int_0^{T+δT}[H_u(x,ψ,u)δu]dt+ \int_0^{T+δT}[H_ψ(x,ψ,u)-\dot x]δψ\,dt
\\&~ ~ ~ ~+\int_0^{T+δT}[H_x(x,ψ,u)+\dot ψ]δx\,dt-[δx(T+δT)ψ(T+δT)-δx(0)ψ(0)]
\\&~ ~ ~ ~+[H(x(T),ψ(T),u(T))-ψ(T)\dot x(T)]δT
\end{align}
The last term compensates for the additional integral over $[T,T+δT]$ that is not present in $L(x,ψ,u,T)$ but used in all the other linearizations.

Now with the fixed boundary conditions for $x$ you get $δx(0)=0$. 
On the other end the situation is a little more involved. Taylor-expanding at $T$ gives $$δx(T+δT)=x_f-x(T+δT)=-\dot x(T)δT+O(δT^2).$$

The other terms but the first give the usual dynamic of Pontryagin's maximum principle, the time variation of the end point gives the additional condition
$$
0=H(x(T),ψ(T),u(T))=−(x(T)^2+u(T)x(T)+u(T)^2)+ψ(T)(x(T)+u(T))
$$
From the local optimality condition for the control $u$ it follows $ψ=x+2u$, so that this last condition is equal
$$
0=−(x(T)^2+u(T)x(T)+u(T)^2)+(x(T)+2u(T))(x(T)+u(T))\\=2u(T)x(T)+u(T)^2=u(T)(2x(T)+u(T))
$$
Following your solution, this means $AB=0$, so that either $x(T)=Ae^t$ or $x(T)=Be^{-t}$. As the boundary values are falling, $A=0$, $B=3$, $e^T=\frac32$.

Comment: I've made a full attempt at the question. Would you say I'm correct that the system cannot be controlled if $T>0$

Comment: I've corrected the treatment of the variable end. It is not true that $δx(T)=0$, as while $x(T)=x_f$, we only know that $[x+δx](T+δT)=x_f$, so there is some diagonal or mean-value argument involved in connecting these two equal values.

Comment: how did you get $AB=0$?. $u=\frac{1}{2}(\psi-x)=-2Be^{-t}$  $0=u(T)(2x(T)+u(T))=u(T)(4+u(T))=-2Be^{-T}(4-2Be^{-T})$ So, $B=0$ or $0=4-2Be^{-T}$???

Comment: Just express $u$ in the formulas for $x$ and $ψ$, to find $u=-2Be^{-t}$, and then also the second factor $(2x+u)=2Ae^t$. I think in general you do not get such a nice product. Your formulas are also correct, $B=0$ leads to contradiction, the other case is $B=2e^T=2\frac32=3$.